# Deserialize to a CRM Entity from ReadAsStreamAsync or ReadAsStringAsync

Tags: c#, deserialization, dynamics-crm, httpresponse, json-deserialization

I'm making a call to a Web API by `HttpResponseMessage response = Helper.SendRequest(...)`  and I need to deserialize the `response` to a `list` of CRM entity `Annotation`.

One of the things we've tried is using `ReasAsStreamAsync`:

```
List<Annotation> _listAnnotation = new List<Annotation>();
MemoryStream stream1 = (MemoryStream)response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Annotation>));

ser.WriteObject(stream1, _listAnnotation);
stream1.Position = 0;
List<Annotation> lst = (List<Annotation>)ser.ReadObject(stream1);
```

but it throws an exception `Stream does not support writing.`

We've also tried the `ReadAsStringAsync`

```
var jsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
jsonString.Wait();
List<Entity> model = (List<Entity>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Entity>>(jsonString.Result);
```

The `jsonString`'s value is

```
[{"Id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","LogicalName":"annotation","Attributes":[{"Key":"filename","Value":"Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileInformation"},{"Key":"documentbody","Value":"JVBERi0xLjUKJfv8/f4KNCAwIG9iago8PAovVGFicyAvUwovU3RydWN0UGFyZW50cyAwCi9QYXJlbnQgMyAwIFIKL1Jlc291cmNlcyA2IDAgUgo......g=="},{"Key":"mimetype","Value":"text/plain"}],"EntityState":null,"FormattedValues":[],"RelatedEntities":[]}]
```

but it says `Cannot create and populate list type Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.AttributeCollection.`

I have interchanged `Entity` and `Annotation` but to no avail.

Which of the approaches are better and closest to what I need to do? Please let me know your suggestions or answers. I have been stuck here for days now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the old "early-bound-types" and `Entity` are compatible with the new web api. You can either create your own POCOs and/or there should be generators that can use the webapi's metadata endpoint to generate classes for you.